# Creating CoverageStore in GeoServer through REST API with external option

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

Following the example from the GeoServer docs [link](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/stores.html#adding-an-existing-shapefile), I tried replicating the same for a GeoTIFF file which is already present in the GeoServer data directory - `$GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/data/raster/test.tif`

My request is as follows:

`curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "file:///data/raster/test.tif" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/Test/coveragestores/test/external.geotiff`

I get the following error:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> PUT /geoserver/rest/workspaces/Test/coveragestores/test/external.geotiff HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: text/plain
> Content-Length: 43
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 879
< Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2022 13:45:31 GMT
< Connection: close
<
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Failed to locate the input file file:&#47;&#47;&#47;data&#47;raster&#47;test.tif</p><p><b>Description</b> The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.68</h3></body></html>* Closing connection 0
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69625433/how-to-create-tiff-layers-by-geoserver-rest-api help?

Comment: The POST request, a coverage store is created. Running the second PUT request it gives the same error again.
HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request
Failed to locate the input file file:&#47;&#47;&#47;data&#47;raster&#47;test.tif

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the wrong location to the server - your tiff is at `$GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/data/raster/test.tif` but you are saying it is at `/data/raster/test.tif` which is almost certainly different.

Try `file://./data/raster/test.tif` instead and see if that is happier, failing that use the actual full path to the file.

Comment: ```file://./data/raster/test.tif``` is also not working, the same error is raised.
But when the same process is done using the UI, only the relative path is taken up, how come it is not taking up through REST API?
Also, providing the actual full path does not help when we need to move the data directory to a different machine as it will have different file paths.

Comment: But even the document [link](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/stores.html#adding-an-existing-shapefile)  mentions providing a relative file path. So does the documentation needs to be changed, or am I missing something in my configuration?

Comment: I can't find the word relative on that page - all the paths are full paths. Without checking the code I'm not sure why the REST api would differ from the GUI